# How to assign properties without casting?

Tags: java, android, view, casting, imageview

I'd like to know if it is possible to assign, for example, the property image resource to an `ImageView` without casting. I know that, without casting, the involved class will be `View` instead of `ImageView`. However, it is annoying create a variable and spend a line when I will not need it in the future.

Example:

Right way:

```
ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img1);
img.setImageResource(idImg);
```

Ideal way:

```
findViewById(R.id.img1).setImageResource(idImg);
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do it without casting but you can do it this way to avoid a variable.

`((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img1)).setImageResource(idImg);`

Comment: Exactly. It was a really simple tip. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use brackets to work with the object you have casted like this:

```
( (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img1) ).setImageResource(idImg)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Class.cast method:

`ImageView.class.cast(findViewById(R.id.img1)).setImageResource(idImg);`